# How to add custom fields in signup page using AWS Amplify

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, serverless, aws-amplify-cli

I have developed a simple app with AWS Amplify and added basic authentication using amplify add auth. I selected the option "Email or Phone Number" and it worked. Now I want to add some more fields like

```
1- first name
2- city
3- country
4- last name
```

Any idea where do I need to implement this? Can I do this with Amplify ADMIN UI? Thanks :)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Are you using AWS Cognito for your auth?

Comment: Hi! Are you using JS? If so, the [Managing user attributes](https://docs.amplify.aws/guides/authentication/managing-user-attributes/q/platform/js) guide has information on how to capture standard and custom attributes.

Answer (score 0):

### For Custom Attributes

1. From the AWS Console, go to the User Pool and select the `Sign-up Experience` tab. You can run `amplify console auth` then select `User Pool` to open the console for you.
2. Scroll down to Custom attributes, then add your custom fields, I added `icecream`.

   > NOTE: Custom attributes **can’t be renamed or deleted** after you create them. Amazon Cognito prepends “custom:” to custom attribute names.
3. Then edit your `amplify-authenticator` directive like below:

Docs that I pieced this together from: https://ui.docs.amplify.aws/components/authenticator?platform=angular#force-new-password-fields
**Important: the `name` attribute in the text-field be in the format `custom:YOUR_CUSTOM_FIELD`**

```
    <!-- angular version here -->
    <amplify-authenticator>
        <ng-template amplifySlot="sign-up-form-fields">

            <amplify-sign-up-form-fields></amplify-sign-up-form-fields>

            <amplify-text-field
                label="Icecream"
                autocomplete="false"
                placeholder="Your Icecream"
                name="custom:icecream"
                type="text">
            </amplify-text-field>

        </ng-template>
    </amplify-authenticator>
```

### For adding additional Standard Attributes

1. Run `amplify update auth`
2. Select `Walkthrough all the auth configurations`
3. When prompted for **Specify read attributes** and **Specify write attributes**, choose the attributes you'd like to enable in your app. https://docs.amplify.aws/guides/authentication/managing-user-attributes/q/platform/js/#configuring-standard-attributes
4. Then add them to your sign-up form directive:

```
<amplify-authenticator [signUpAttributes]="['address','preferred_username']"></amplify-authenticator>
```

Answer (score 0):

Now, these kinds of options("custom:xxx") are deprecated.

They released one more option to add custom attributes.
[More information about these attributes can be found here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-settings-attributes.html#user-pool-settings-custom-attributes)

If you want to add custom attributes,
CognitoUserAttributeKey.custom(_key): <attribute_value>,

1. _key denotes the custom attribute constant string.
2. attribute_value denotes the value of the attributes

Example:
CognitoUserAttributeKey.custom("village"): "Nachipatty",